# Recurrence Relation of T(n)

Tags: real-analysis

I's stuck on finding the recurrence relation of:
T(0) = 0

It looks like the recurrence must be n^2 because of T(n-1) + cn but I want the exact process of getting to the actual solution.

This is what I have done so far:

T(n-1) = (1/n-1)(.....(T(n-2))+(n-1)c

T(n-2) = (1/n-2)(.....(T(n-3))+(n-2)c
.............

Answer (score 2):

You have
$t(0) = 0$
and
$t(n)
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t(k) +cn
$.

From the last,
$nt(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t(k) +cn^2
$.

Doing this for $n+1$,
$(n+1)t(n+1)
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} t(k) +c(n+1)^2
$.

Subtracting these,
$(n+1)t(n+1)-nt(n)
=t(n)+c((n+1)^2-n^2)
$
or
$(n+1)t(n+1)
=(n+1)t(n)+c(2n+1)
$
or
$t(n+1)
=t(n)+c\frac{2n+1}{n+1}
$
or
$t(n+1)-t(n)
=c\frac{2n+1}{n+1}
=c(2-\frac{1}{n+1})
$.

Summing from
$0$ to $n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
t(n)-t(0)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (t(k+1)-t(k))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (c(2-\frac{1}{k+1}))\\
&=2cn-c\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}\\
&=2cn-c\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\\
&=2cn-cH_n\\
&=2cn-c(\ln n + \gamma+O(1/n))\\
\end{array}
$

---

The more general case is almost as easy.

Suppose
$t(n)
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t(k) +f(n)
$.

From the last,
$nt(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t(k) +nf(n)
$.

Doing this for $n+1$,
$(n+1)t(n+1)
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} t(k) +(n+1)f(n+1)
$.

Subtracting these,

$\begin{array}\\
(n+1)t(n+1)-nt(n)
&=t(n)+((n+1)f(n+1)-nf(n))\\
\text{or}\\
(n+1)t(n+1)
&=(n+1)t(n)+((n+1)f(n+1)-nf(n))\\
\text{or}\\
t(n+1)
&=t(n)+\frac{(n+1)f(n+1)-nf(n)}{n+1}\\
&=t(n)+\frac{(n+1)f(n+1)-(n+1)f(n)+f(n)}{n+1}\\
&=t(n)+f(n+1)-f(n)+\frac{f(n)}{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

or
$t(n+1)-t(n)
=f(n+1)-f(n)+\frac{f(n)}{n+1}
$.

Summing from
$0$ to $n-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
t(n)-t(0)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (t(k+1)-t(k))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (f(k+1)-f(k)+\frac{f(k)}{k+1})\\
&=f(n)-f(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f(k)}{k+1}\\
&=f(n)(1-\frac1{n+1})-f(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f(k)}{k+1}\\
&=f(n)\frac{n}{n+1}-f(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f(k)}{k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: why you prove it for n+1 times? Any specific reason? Your approach is quite different from mine @marty cohen

Comment: I don't *prove* it for n+1. I use the recurrence for n and n+1, and combine them (by subtracting) to get a simpler recurrence.

Comment: mm I see, I'm not used to that technique, is this geometric series? How could it be using the iterating method (technique I'm trying to solve)? @marty cohen

Comment: I have more problems of these, so if I could fully understand what its going on, I can easily do the other ones

Comment: Whenever you have $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t(k)$ in a recurrence for $t(n)$, you get get rid of the sum by subtracting a suitable multiple of $t(n)$ from $t(n+1)$.

Comment: I was able to follow now, thanks a lot for your help @marty cohen